# Não consigo fazer start ao listener do oracle

Tags: linux, oracle

Estou tentando instalar o Oracle numa maquina linux para ser acedida em cobol.
O sqlplus está funcionando, consigo executar comandos de sql.

Ao tentar inicar o listener do oracle, estou a receber o erro:

> Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=network,
>   facility=TNSTNS-12545:

Já tentei várias configurações dos ficheiros listener.ora e tnsnames.ora, mas não consigo fazer start do listener. Estou trabalhando numa maquina linux sem opção gráfica.

O objectivo final é correr um programa em microfocus cobol acedendo a uma tabela em oracle.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: já fiz algumas alterações à pergunta. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caro Orlando,

O arquivo listener.ora pode estar no local errado ou não possuir as permissões corretas.

Certifique-se de que está no caminho: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

O proprietário do arquivo deve ser [oracle-user].[oracle-group]

A permissão deve ser 644

Caso verifique que está tudo correto tente configurar o listener através do netca.

Comment: Em primeiro lugar muito obrigado. A única situação que não estava feita era "O proprietário do arquivo deve ser [oracle-user].[oracle-group]", já fiz a alteração e continua o mesmo erro. Quanto ao netca penso ser em ambiente gráfico que a minha máquina não tem instalado.

Comment: Orlando! você pode utilizar o smartty (http://smartty.sysprogs.com/) que conta com o Xming embarcado para rodar o netca

Comment: Efectivamente a variável $ORACLE_HOME tinha um directório a mais.